# How to set dynamic payer id and receiver id in each new request while paypal adaptive payments using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am able to set the *receiver id* dynamically while the payer username, password, and signature are static to create a PayPal object during PayPal adaptive payments using PayPal adaptive package in Node JS.

Is it possible to set both payer/receiver id dynamically?

For example:
If I send both payer email and receiver email registered with PayPal, would it work or is there any way to make it work?